# How to extract a value from a set of Strings?

Tags: rust

I have a set of strings where I am getting using `lines()` function. The Strings are like

```
abcdjf hfdf
test oinf=ddfn
cbdfk test12345=my value
mngf jdk
```

I want to get `my value` from the above strings. So, I am using the code as

```
body.lines()
        .filter(|s| s.contains("test12345="))
        .map(|x| x.split("=")[1]).to_string();
```

But it's not working and not returning any value. What is the correct code for this?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. We can't tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterator::map()` returns an interator, not a value, so you can't use `to_string()` on it. On the other hand, `String::split()` does not return a slice, but an iterator, so you can't access the value like `[1]`; instead, you must access it with the iterator API. As far as Rust can know, there could be multiple lines that contain "test12345=", so it must deal with that. To do so, you would need to `.collect()` your results in a `Vec<String>`:

```rust
let values: Vec<String> = body.lines()
    .filter(|s| s.contains("test12345="))
    .map(|x| x.split("=").nth(1).unwrap().to_string())
    .collect();
```

Now, that doens't look nice nor idiomatic, does it?. Since the `.filter().map()` is a common pattern, there's `.filter_map()` that accomplishes both in a single function. It's quite handy that it expects that the closure to return `Option<T>`, so you could use `?` for early returns if needed.

```rust
let values: Vec<String> = body.lines()
    .filter_map(|line| {
        if !line.contains("test12345=") {
            return None;
        }

        line.split("=").nth(1).map(String::from)
    })
    .collect();
```

`Iterator::nth()` will give you the nth element on the iterator, but it could not exist, that's why it returns an `Option`. By using `Option::map()` you can convert from `&str` to `String` *if* there's a value. In this case by passing the `String::from` function as the argument to `.map()` it will convert from `Option<&str>` to `Option<String>` which matches the return type of the closure, so now you'll have what you're looking for

Comment: Why do you suggest that the first code snippet "doesn't look nice or idiomatic"? It seems just as readable as the second one, if not more so. One might even argue that, with the exception of using `unwrap()`, the first snippet is _more_ idiomatic/elegant because it composes iterator combinators rather than encoding the whole business logic in a single closure with an early return.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you cannot call `to_string` on an iterator. Second `split` returns an iterator as well, so you cannot index it (i.e. `[1]`), instead you'd need to call [`nth(1)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth).

```rust
body
    .lines()
    .filter(|s| s.contains("test12345="))
    .map(|x| x.split("=").nth(1))
```

In case there can be multiple `=` after the first one, which you want to retain in the *value*, then instead use [`splitn(2, "=")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.splitn), i.e.:

```rust
.map(|x| x.splitn(2, "=").nth(1))
```

Also, given your `filter` then everything is needlessly wrapped in `Some(..)`. To avoid that, you can combine the `filter` and `map` using [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map).

```rust
body
    .lines()
    .filter_map(|s| {
        if s.contains("test12345=") {
            s.splitn(2, "=").nth(1)
        } else {
            None
        }
    });
```

Since you attempted to use `to_string`. Then if you do want the iterator to return `String` instead of `&str` then you can add `.map(ToString::to_string)` either after `nth(2)` or after `filter_map(..)`.